# How to arrange/make an array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a date range 1st Nov to 30th Nov.

I block the date 3rd Nov to 6th Nov And 15th Nov to 20th Nov.

Now I want to show the available dates like 1th to 2nd Nov, 7th to 14th Nov And 21th to 30th Nov.

This is my array of date range

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-01
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-02
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-03
            [IsBlocked] => true
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-04
            [IsBlocked] => true
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-05
            [IsBlocked] => true
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-06
            [IsBlocked] => true
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-07
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-08
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-09
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-10
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-11
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-12
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-13
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-14
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-15
            [IsBlocked] => true
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-16
            [IsBlocked] => true
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-17
            [IsBlocked] => true
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-18
            [IsBlocked] => true
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-19
            [IsBlocked] => true
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-20
            [IsBlocked] => true
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-21
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-22
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-23
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-24
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-25
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-26
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-27
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-28
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-29
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2023-11-30
            [IsBlocked] => false
        )

)
```

And I want to

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start_date] => 2023-11-01
            [end_date] => 2023-11-02
        )
        
    [1] => Array
    (
        [start_date] => 2023-11-07
        [end_date] => 2023-11-14
    )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start_date] => 2023-11-21
            [end_date] => 2023-11-30
        )
)
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

I'm try using this array but it's not happening.

```
foreach($dates as $calDay) {
   if($calDay['IsBlocked'] == "true") {
       $closeDates[] = $calDay['date'];
   } else {
       $openDates[] = $calDay['date'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dates = [
    // ... your existing array of dates ...
];

$availableRanges = [];
$currentRange = null;

foreach ($dates as $calDay) {
    if ($calDay['IsBlocked'] == "true") {
        // If the current range exists, add it to the availableRanges array
        if ($currentRange) {
            $availableRanges[] = $currentRange;
            $currentRange = null;
        }
    } else {
        // If the current range does not exist, create a new range
        if (!$currentRange) {
            $currentRange = [
                'start_date' => $calDay['date'],
                'end_date' => $calDay['date']
            ];
        }
        // Update the end_date of the current range
        $currentRange['end_date'] = $calDay['date'];
    }
}

// Add the last available range if it exists
if ($currentRange) {
    $availableRanges[] = $currentRange;
}
```

In this code, the `$availableRanges` array will store the final result, and the `$currentRange` variable keeps track of the current range being processed. Whenever a blocked date is encountered, the current range is added to the `$availableRanges` array and reset to null. If an available date is found, a new range is created or the end_date of the current range is updated.

At the end of the loop, the last available range (if it exists) is added to the `$availableRanges` array.

The resulting `$availableRanges` array will contain the start and end dates of the available date ranges.

Comment: Thanks @kedar it's working perfectly again thanks you save my day.

Answer (score 0):

Input array:

```
$input = [
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-01', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-02', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-03', 'IsBlocked' => true ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-04', 'IsBlocked' => true ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-05', 'IsBlocked' => true ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-06', 'IsBlocked' => true ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-07', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-08', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-09', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-10', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-11', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-12', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-13', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-14', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-15', 'IsBlocked' => true ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-16', 'IsBlocked' => true ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-17', 'IsBlocked' => true ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-18', 'IsBlocked' => true ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-19', 'IsBlocked' => true ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-20', 'IsBlocked' => true ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-21', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-22', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-23', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-24', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-25', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-26', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-27', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-28', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-29', 'IsBlocked' => false ],
  [ 'date' => '2023-11-30', 'IsBlocked' => false ]
];
```

First step is to collect the last date before and the first date after each change of 'IsBlocked':

```
$dates = [];

for ($i = 0, $iMax = count($input); $i < $iMax; $i++) {
  if ($i === 0 || $i === $iMax - 1) {
    $dates[] = $input[$i]['date'];
  } elseif ($input[$i]['IsBlocked'] !== $input[$i - 1]['IsBlocked']) {
    $dates[] = $input[$i - 1]['date'];
    $dates[] = $input[$i]['date'];
  }
}
```

This results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2023-11-01
    [1] => 2023-11-02
    [2] => 2023-11-03
    [3] => 2023-11-06
    [4] => 2023-11-07
    [5] => 2023-11-14
    [6] => 2023-11-15
    [7] => 2023-11-20
    [8] => 2023-11-21
    [9] => 2023-11-30
)
```

Second step is to chunk this array into pairs of two and to filter the dates:

```
$result = array_values(
  array_filter(
    array_chunk($dates, 2),
    fn($key) => $key % 2 === ( $input[0]['IsBlocked'] ? 1 : 0 ),
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
  )
);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2023-11-01
            [1] => 2023-11-02
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2023-11-07
            [1] => 2023-11-14
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2023-11-21
            [1] => 2023-11-30
        )

)
```